# Multiple object tabs for same object with different lisview

Tags: list-view, tab, app

There is an object called equipment with filter ALL-BE, is it possible to create a second tab in the same app for the same object but with a different fixed filter ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. Each object gets one tab. You can create any number of list views, and each user can choose to pin the list view of their choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create a new app page on App Builder. Edit the page on the App Builder by dragging across a list view component, select the object you want to filter (Equipment) and apply any other filters you need.